# Java Regex intersection (&&) is not commutative

Tags: java, regex, character-class

The character class intersection operator `&&`, by definition of its function, should be commutative. `[a&&b]` should match exactly the same characters as `[b&&a]` for any a and b. I've found that the following patterns all satisfy this criterion.

`[a-z&&abcd]` same as `[abcd&&a-z]`

`[a-z&&ab[cd]]` same as `[ab[cd]&&a-z]`

`[a-z&&[ab][cd]]` same as `[[ab][cd]&&a-z]`

They are all equivalent to `[abcd]`. However, if expressed `[a-z&&[ab]cd]`, this is no longer true. That expression only matches `c` and `d`, but not `a` and `b`. However, the flipped version `[[ab]cd&&a-z]` matches all four characters like the other patterns. In other words

`[[ab]cd&&a-z]` not same as `[a-z&&[ab]cd]`

I went into the sources of `Pattern` to find out why this is, and I found that this is how intersection is implemented (Java 1.8.0_60 JDK)

```
case '&':
    // ...
    ch = next();
    if (ch == '&') {
        ch = next();
        CharProperty rightNode = null;
        while (ch != ']' && ch != '&') {
            if (ch == '[') {
                if (rightNode == null)
                    rightNode = clazz(true);
                else
                    rightNode = union(rightNode, clazz(true));
            } else { // abc&&def
                unread();
                rightNode = clazz(false); // here is what happens
            }
            ch = peek();
        }
```

Notice that the marked line is

```
rightNode = clazz(false);
```

and not

```
rightNode = union(rightNode, clazz(true));
```

In other words, on the right side of `&&`, whenever the first character that is not inside a nested character class is encountered, the pattern parser assumes there is nothing before it. So after `&&`, the parser reads `[ab]` into `rightNode`, then reads `cd`, but instead of merging with `[ab]`, it just overwrites it.

I know that practically no one writes a regex like `[a-z&&[ab]cd]`, but still, the documentation implies that it should work. Is this a bug in the implementation, or is it actually supposed to work this way?

Comment: In Java [regex documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [character class docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html), there are no examples like `[a-z&&[ab]cd]`. It is clear that one should use a character class after `&&` for the union/intersection to work.

Comment: If the `&&` has to be followed by a character class, then why does `[a-z&&ab[cd]]` work just fine? That matches a, b, c and d.

Comment: can you list test cases (input and output examples) which proves 'I've found that the following patterns all satisfy this criterion.'

Comment: As for me, this is *un*documented behavior that one cannot rely on.